# How to see manifest file for app in Android market?

Tags: android, google-play

How to download the apk? How to see the manifest file?

Is there a website that does this?

Comment: why do you want to see the manifest file? When you try to install an app, you can see all the permissions before hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getjar for exemple to download apk, unlike the market it doens't have the system persmission, so it download the apk on your sd card and then prompte for install. you can get the apk there.

Or use a backup manager like astro to get your own apps.

You can use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to unpack apk and get a readeable manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You cant view the manifest file of an application from the android market. You can view all the permissions ,features , hardware required etc for the app from the webpage for the app in android market.

You can get apps from other sites were you can download the apk and get the manifest file.